# Vb Script to refresh excel with Credentials

Tags: security, vbscript

I have an excel file that has data connections linked to SharePoint.
It asks for credentials to connect to SharePoint
I already have a VBScript in place that refreshes the excel automatically and saves it.

Is there a way in which I can embed the credentials and enter into the pop-up.

I am new to VBScript. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Can* you embed the credentials? Probably. The real question you should as is *should* you? If anyone were to gain access to your script, they would have the username and password to a domain account (or even a domain admin account if that is what you are using). Not good.